# Erratic behaviour after changing from package.config to package references

Tags: c#, visual-studio, package

When doing small changes to an existing project, I also used the context menu in VisualStudio 2017 to migrate the package.config to package references. The conversion report said: everything okay.

Then, it got weird:

- some unit tests (MSTest) started to fail, but not all. Although the causing call of an external (unchanged) method was executed during  [TestInitialize]
- When debugging, variables can not be accessed anymore, stepwise debugging skips lines, ...
- The same lines of code work in the main class, but fail when called from a unit test ...
- . . .

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the erratic behaviour seems to be caused by a wrong package reference: The macro created a reference to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI` from my references. The nuget info for `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI` says: do not reference directly.
[Nuget Package Manager Info for Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyHyZ.png)
After replacing it with a nuget reference to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` the code worked as before.